# Membership Start date and end date does not exist for recurring contributions(of type member dues)

Tags: civimember, stripe

I have an issue wherein if someones selects recurring option for member dues, it does not show membership start and end date.
Is that a normal behaviour ?

CiviCRM 5.40.3

Payment Processor - Stripe
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The  membership start date and End date will be populated once Civi gets response from the Stripe about the payment. Once the related contribution is set to completed the membership start date and End date will be set.

Incase the contribution status is updated correctly but not the membership than probably the date update must have failed while doing the related component update.

Comment: I have added an endpoint in stripe , so whenever a payment is sucessful, it updates the membership and contribution status to completed , the reason for adding it is, if I dont it just keeps it as pending status, so I added my own endpoint, but now I  have noticed the start and end dates are empty.

Comment: Should I update the start and end date along with the status in the endpoint which I have created ?

Comment: I have also added an endpoint /civicrm/payment/ipn/1 suggested in civicrm docs https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/recurring/

Comment: Why did you had to create your own end point? Doesn't Stripe extensions creates a one for you? I would say delete the endpoint and create a one from civicrm status page

Comment: while removing custom endpoint and replacing it with /civicrm/payment/ipn/1 worked but I see for a monthly membership type on civicrm, under Active Recurring Contributions it shows as "Every 1 year" which should be every 1 month

Comment: Subscription created on stripe also shows every-1-year whereas its for monthly membership type